# How make "group by" in Django models?

Tags: python, django

I googled it before asking this again, but this did not help me.

This is SQL query:

```
SELECT cmcmodels_bootconfigs.fabric, cmcmodels_bootconfigs.bootData FROM cmcmodels_bootconfigs GROUP BY fabric
```

How to make group by via django models?

This did not work for me:
`BootConfigs.objects.values('fabric').annotate(Count('fabric'))`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It would help if you could show the relevant parts of the models and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, annotating a count is much different to grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is work in my project:
`BootConfigs.objects.order_by().values('fabric', 'bootData').distinct()`

This allows me to select only one (first) copy of each line, where 'fabric' is same.

Answer (score 0):

what is problem in

```
BootConfigs.objects.values('fabric').annotate(total=Sum('fabric'))
```

Answer is based on how to use group by in django query set

Above query will give you only fabric value however if you want more field values try something like.

```
.values(
'column to group by', 'aggregate', 'extra field1', 'extra field 2'
)
```